# Google Cloud Platform instance local port Connection refused

Tags: sockets, tcp

I'm using stanza on GCP and it requires localhost:9000. I have a firewall rule enabling all access to the VM. Here are all my firewalls:

```
NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY  DISABLED
allow-tcp-9000          default  INGRESS    1000      all                                 False
default-allow-http      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80                              False
default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443                             False
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp                                False
default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp        False
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389                            False
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22                              False
```

I checked my netstat. It gives:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.4:37918        209.85.146.95:443       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.4:53470        169.254.169.254:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    208 10.128.0.4:22           24.90.233.8:50870       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.128.0.4:37006        74.125.70.95:443        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*
```

I checked other questions on stackoverflow and it seems that the problem is localhost:9000 is not listened. What can I do in this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey- I dont see any process running on port 9000 under netstat output.
Can you make sure you have a process running that listen on port 9000?

Comment: How do you run your app on the port 9000

Comment: @pradeep @guillaumeblaquiere Hi, I use `java -Xmx5G -cp /my-path/sqlova-shallow-layer/stanford-corenlp-4.0.0/* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 60000 -threads 5 -maxCharLength 100000 -quiet True -serverProperties corenlp_server-548b88c54e034f5a.props -preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,depparse`, and it gives `stanza.server.client.PermanentlyFailedException: Timed out waiting for service to come alive.`